# how to eliminate command exception issue in gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have this command
gsutil rsync -r -x '".*.jpg$"' File Share\data\Home Drive gs://sdefs01/Home Drive

this is to exclude any .jpg file to be copied to my google bucket.

however, it returns an error:

commandexceptions: the rsync command accept at most 2 arguments.

the command example that I refer to is from google cloud support page.

please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the source directory path inside double quotes as it contains spaces.